# socket.io and jquery load

Tags: jquery, socket.io

I am trying to call a webpage that is being served up via socket.io and i get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foo.bar:12354/.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://foo.bar' is therefore not allowed access.

Below is my very simple jq code for calling the page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#x').load('http://foo.bar:12354');
});
```

Here is my simple socket.io example:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(12354);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
        socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
        });
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});                                     
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://foo.bar:12354");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        next();
});
```

When i pull up the page directly using http://foo.bar:12354 the page loads fine.

One forum suggested i needed to include an apache CORS approval, but putting this into a dot-access didnt help:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This seems like it should be a pretty simple task but it has me stumped.  any suggestions are thoughts would be most appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to your express app.use:    `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: thanks pherris - that was the first thing i tried.  i also put in a console.log line before the res.header stuff.   the line would fire off when i went in using the h t t p : / / foo . bar/ url, but when i used the jQ load it would not fire off at all.  that should be a big clue to me, but i am still not seeing it.

Comment: where is this code, index.html? `$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#x').load('http://foo.bar:12354');
});`

Comment: the jq load is going into another window - i am attempting to simulate an iframe using jQuery - the question was rephrased here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372043/express-io-and-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, express is serving your static content so you wouldn't need jQuery's load() method to fetch your page - your content is simply whatever HTML/JS/CSS is in index.html file (which will also establish the websocket connection to the server from which it was just served).

It looks from [the docs](http://socket.io/docs/) that express and socket.io can use the same port (no cross origin stuff needed). So, I'd suggest switching to port 80 and following the example in the how-to section but without the jQuery load() piece:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Then you should just be able to hit http://foo.bar (port 80) from your browser and see the console.log in both your browser and on the server. I don't think that you will need anything for cross-origin requests, since the socket connects to the same port that served the static content.

Comment: thank you ferris - i didnt make myself totally clear - so i reposted the question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372043/express-io-and-jquery